# GAE Request Timeout when user uploads csv file and receives new csv file as response

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app on GAE that takes csv input from a web form and stores it to a blob, does some stuff to obtain new information using input from the csv file, then uses csv.writer on self.response.out to write a new csv file and prompt the user to download it.  It works well, but my problem is if it takes over 60 seconds it times out.  I've tried to setup the do some stuff part as a task in task queue, and it would work, except I can't make the user wait while this is running, and there's no way of calling the post that would write out the new csv file automatically when the task queue is complete, and having the user periodically push a button to see if it is done is less than optimal.

Is there a better solution to a problem like this other than using the task queue and having the user have to manually push a button periodically to see if the task is complete?

Comment: you could "push the button" with javascript, or use the channel API to push a message to the user when done.

Comment: thanks! i'll give it a try. i could even setup a sliding status bar using messages from channel api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is 60s limit for requests, you could consider to use App Engine Modules that allow you to control scaling type of a module/version. Basically there are three scaling types available.

**Manual Scaling**

Such a module runs continuously. Requests can run indefinitely.

**Basic Scaling**

Such a module creates an instance when the application receives a request. The instance will be turned down when the app becomes idle. Requests can run indefinitely.

**Automatic Scaling**

The same scaling policy that App Engine has used since its inception. It is based on request rate, response latencies, and other application metrics. There is 60-second deadline for HTTP requests.

You can find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/).

Comment: Thank you! I would eventually like to set it up on task queue and use the channel API, but after struggling with getting it all working nicely all day, I just changed my scaling.  It's not the most elegant solution, but does the job for now.  I completely overlooked app engine modules.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that the user is left hanging there.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options:

1. Use a timer in your client to check periodically (i.e. every 15 seconds) if the file is ready. This is the simplest option that requires only a few lines of code.
2. Use the Channel API. It's elegant, but it's an overkill unless you face similar problems frequently.
3. Email the results to the user.

Comment: +1 @user2934565 I think the first option is the easiest one and not that bad if you actually know that it will be finished in couple of minutes.. in a long run if you have too many files and too many users you might consider implementing Channel API or if takes more than a few minutes sending the email..